# WPF DevExpress GridControl MVVM How to get grid layout string value created in code behind back to viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a DevExpress GridControl named "CylMgmtDataGrid". A user can modify the layout of the grid (order of columns, the visibility of columns, etc.). When the layout is changed by the user, a "LayoutChanged" event fires and a function is called in the code behind where I can determine different attributes of the grid layout.  In this function, I can create a string that contains all the layout information.  I need to inform a viewmodel GridLayout string property when this layout string value changes, so that the viewmodel can save the layout information.

My question is, what is the proper MVVM way to transfer the layout string value built in the code behind back to the viewmodel GridLayout property?

Comment: The dependency property idea sounds like the way to go ... Thanks Ed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this properly, level one would be to give your view a [dependency property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview) for layout information and bind it in the XAML to the viewmodel's `LayoutInformation` property. Then your handler would update the dependency property, and the binding would update the viewmodel. If you give the dependency property a PropertyChanged handler, you could make it a two-way binding and cleanly handle the later update from the viewmodel back to the view.

This lets your view remain agnostic about the actual type of the viewmodel.

Since this is useful functionality to generalize, and because you're looking for a nice clean respectable MVVM design, we can do something a lot nicer:

Take the code from your event handler and wrap it in an [attached property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview), so it could be conveniently be reused in different views. This would replace the view's dependency property. The attached property's PropertyChanged handler would set up whatever events are needed on the GridControl.

Usage would look something like this:

```
<dxg:GridControl
    local:DXGridExt.LayoutInformation="{Binding SomeVMProperty}"
```

If the layout information is all in one property of the GridControl, you could also implement this as a value converter, but my impression is that's not the case.